# Flashing isn't going as expected

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, rom-flashing, fastboot, miui, xiaomi

I'm flashing my device (Xiaomi Mi5) - with MiFlash Beta tool and unlocked bootloader - the official MIUI 8.0 ROM Global stable. The problem is that it's been like an hour and a half flashing it and still didn't finish[image: MiFlash Beta]
The progress bar was filled when the elapse time was 1500, and it is now in 9000 and keeps increasing. I'm flashing it in Fastboot Mode.
What should I do? I'm afraid of stop the flashing process in case I brick the device. Should I stop it? If so, how? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What happened to you? Mine is at 1 hour now too, and I'm afraid of shutting it down.

Comment: I just closed the flash tool,  rebooted the phone and nothing changed. So i downloaded this flash tool (http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=345667&highlight=miflash%2Btool) and repeated the process (enter fastboot mode and flash the global official stable rom),  and it worked perfectly.  I guess hou have bootloader unlocked,  else won't let you flash it. @michael